# How Click button to Open browser?

Tags: android

Its working properly in every API level, but not working properly on Lolipop(api 21)
Code is here:

```
Intent internetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                    .parse("http://www.google.com/"));
            internetIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                    "com.android.browser",
                    "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
            internetIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(internetIntent);
```

Comment: what  do you mean by "not working properly"? any exception

Comment: Is there a reason you set a specific component?

Comment: you should NOT specify a hardcoded package for the browser, that is poor coding style, allow the user to specify which browser they would want to use. User an implicit intent to bring up the browser instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code:

```
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"));
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I think he is trying to open with default browser :P

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it wont work in Lollipop, or may not work on any brand Manufactured(Sony,Samsung) phones, because you are trying to open an application with package name `com.android.browser`

```
internetIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                    "com.android.browser",
                    "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
```

In Lollipop default browser is chrome, which has package name something else. And there is no application with package `com.android.browser` in Lollipop.

Same thing can happen to any other Sony/Samsung phones.

What you can do is either call for a `Application Chooser Dialog` or `find the default browser application, and open it`

1) Code for Application chooser:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://"));
startActivity(intent);
```

2) Code to Find default app and launch it:

```
        ComponentName cn=null;
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://"));
        ResolveInfo resolveInfo = packageManager.resolveActivity(browserIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        if (resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.equals("android")) {
            List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(browserIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            for (ResolveInfo info : resolveInfos) {
                if (!info.activityInfo.packageName.equals("android")) {
                    cn = new ComponentName(info.activityInfo.packageName, info.activityInfo.name);
                }
            }
            if(cn==null)
            cn = new ComponentName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
        } else {
            cn = new ComponentName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
        }

        if(cn!=null){
            Intent openIntent = new Intent();
            openIntent.setComponent(cn);
            openIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"));
            startActivity(openIntent);
        }
```